# Sorting integers in an array from largest to smallest. Negative ints not working

Tags: java, arrays

Recently I created a program that takes the ints inside of an array and puts them in another array from largest to smallest, but it doesn't work when you insert negatives. It prints a 0 rather than the negative integer.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class g2lArrays2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = {15,31,7,2,7};
        int[] place = new int [nums.length];
        int[] definer = new int [nums.length];
        int a = 0,b = 0,c;
        place[0] = a;
        place[1] = 1;
        for (int i1 = 0; i1<place.length; i1++) {
        for (int i = 0; i<nums.length; i++) {
            if (nums[i] > a) {
                place[i1]=nums[i];
                a=place[i1];
                definer[i]=1;
            }
        }
        a = 0;
        for (c = definer.length-1; b==0 && c>-1; c--) {
            if (definer[c]==1) {
                b=c;
            }
        }
        nums[b]=0;
        b=0;
        for (int i2 = 0; i2<definer.length; i2++) {
            definer[i2]=0;
        }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(place));
    }
}
```

It works otherwise, but like I've stated, just not with negative integers. So I'm curious about what I'm doing wrong and if there's a more efficient way to sort this program. All feedback is appreciated.

Comment: There are many ways to sort a collection of things, you might want to look into [sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) for some insight.

Comment: @Mureinik it's probably homework.

Comment: I strongly recommend stepping through this with a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i think FairPlay answer is totally the best way to sort a array. That said you asked why your code was having problems and that is what i will try to explain here.

First you are printing the array named place and so i will only comment about the places where the code involves that specific array.

this is the parts in your code that affect the place array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] nums = {15,31,7,2,7};
    int[] place = new int [nums.length];
    int[] definer = new int [nums.length];
    int a = 0,b = 0,c;
    place[0] = a;
    place[1] = 1;
    for (int i1 = 0; i1<place.length; i1++) {
    for (int i = 0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] > a) {
            place[i1]=nums[i];
            a=place[i1];
            definer[i]=1;
```

Okay first lets clear this. First things to pay attention is correct identation and create lines breaks whenever you think it is good. Second, when creating a variable that will only be used in a loop or inside a for name them i, j or k and repeat them if possible (this is something i do so it is more of a tip than a rule).

Here is the clean code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] nums = {15,31,7,2,7};
    int[] place = new int [nums.length];
    int[] definer = new int [nums.length];

    int a = 0,
    int b = 0;

    place[0] = a;
    place[1] = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < place.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {

            if (nums[j] > a) {

                //first a = 0 just so i remember
                //int[] nums = {15,31,7,2,7};

                place[i] = nums[j];
                a = place[i];
                definer[j] = 1;
```

Got it! The problem is exactly in the if above. the problem is in the nums[j] > a. Clearly a negative number wont pass the check ever and that is the problem.

EDIT: Okay i just realized i misread where the first for ends (bad identation) but the problem is the same. You will have problems with negative numbers because your a and b are set to 0 every loop. The 0 that appear in the place of negative numbers are because you added b = 0 in the nums array.

To solve that you should just use array.sort() as FairPlay said in his answer. it is not worth the trouble trying to fix this.